# Android Gridview Activity is not starting

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity

I have a Gridview and when I press on the first item Activity gives error but the second and third item launches and I have checked in the manifest as well all activities are registered and I couldn't make out what's my mistake I am posting all data please help me .

Comment: Logcat info

http://pastebin.com/AYhDxr9V


Main Activity code

http://pastebin.com/4tyHaque

Customgrid class

http://pastebin.com/fgimPUDG

Comment: Friends i have posted the log cat and MainActivity and customgrid class codes in the above links please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your Product1.onCreate(), which throws a NullPointerException and has nothing to do with GridView.